# how to call the method of controller in routeProvider resolve function

Tags: angularjs

I wanna update the data and then show the view bound with this controller, the code is as follow

```
    angular.module('myApp.student', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/student', {
            templateUrl: 'student/student.html',
            css: 'student/assets/student.css',
            controller: 'studentCtrl',
            demand: 'admin'
        });
    }])
    .controller('studentCtrl', ['$scope', 'baseDataUrl', '$http', function($scope, baseDataUrl, $http) {
        $scope.update = function() {
            $http.get(baseDataUrl + '/student/list').then(function(res) {
                $scope.students = res.data;
            });
        };

        $scope.orderProp = "name";
        $scope.update();
    }]);
```

how can i do this as there is no way to inject the controller to the config as I know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something like...

```
angular.module('myApp.student', ['ngRoute'])
.config('routeConfig', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/student', {
        templateUrl: 'student/student.html',
        css: 'student/assets/student.css',
        controller: 'studentCtrl',
        demand: 'admin',
        resolve: { students : function ($http, baseDataUrl) {
                return $http.get(baseDataUrl + '/student/list').then(function (res) {
                    return res.data;
                });
            }
        }
    });
})
.controller('studentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, students) {
    $scope.students = students;

    $scope.orderProp = "name";
}]);
```

Note that `baseDataUrl` must either be a constant, or a provider that calls a function to get the required data (in which case, it should be something like `baseDataUrl.getUrl()`).

With this, it is ensured that every time the `/student` route is accessed, the scope variable `$scope.students` contains updated data.

Comment: @Sladar please select this as the Accepted Answer if this solves your query. Thanks! :)